# Airflow on Kubernetes: couldn't parse image reference

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

Running Airflow in GKE.
When scheduler spawn workers I am facing the next problem:

```
Failed to apply default image tag "my_registry_address_without_https:python:3.9.4-alpine": couldn't parse image reference "my_registry_address_without_https:python:3.9.4-alpine": invalid reference format
```

In `airflow.cfg` I have the next configs:

```
# The repository of the Kubernetes Image for the Worker to Run
worker_container_repository = my_registry_address_without_https

# The tag of the Kubernetes Image for the Worker to Run
worker_container_tag = python:3.9.4-alpine
```

It supposes to parse properly, but can't understand, what am I missing..

Comment: Hello, try to change `worker_container_tag = python:3.9.4-alpine` to  `worker_container_tag = python:3.9.5-alpine`? [Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) you can find, that 3.9.5-alpine is supported tag.

Comment: The problem is not with the version, cause I pull not from the Docker hub, but from the private repository `invalid reference format` is the error(

Comment: In the reference: `my_registry_address_without_https:python:3.9.4-alpine` I don't like two `:` characters. Look at [official docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/). If this repository is private could you change his name to avoid using `:` character in his tag? Or you can try separate `worker_container_tag` to `worker_container_tag = {python:3.9.4-alpine}`? You can also try to separate with `"` or `'` characters instead of `{}`.

Comment: That is why my question is here (I also don't like two `:`), based on Airflow docs, this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the address of the repository. It supposes to be registry/image:

```
# The repository of the Kubernetes Image for the Worker to Run
worker_container_repository = my_registry_address_without_https/python

# The tag of the Kubernetes Image for the Worker to Run
worker_container_tag = 3.9.4-alpine
```